# Dynamically Setting ngModelOptions in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I've got the following snippet:

```
<input type="date" ng-model="arrival" ng-model-options="{timezone: 'PST'}" />
<input type="time" ng-model="arrival" ng-model-options="{timezone: 'PST'}" />
{{arrival}}
```

That works properly (the date is displayed in UTC time converted from PST). I'm now trying to make the 'PST' option dynamic:

```
<select ng-model="timezone>
  <option value="PST">PST</option>
  <option value="EST">EST</option>
</select>
<input type="date" ng-model="arrival" ng-model-options="{timezone: timezone}" />
<input type="time" ng-model="arrival" ng-model-options="{timezone: timezone}" />
{{arrival}}
```

However, changing the timezone never update the arrival (it appears that binding doesn't work with `nd-model-options`). Any way I can force the fields to refresh when the timezone is changed?

**Edit**

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/10nfqow9/

Comment: Try having an object in ng-model-options, Something like:

`ng-model-options="options"`

and 

`$scope.options={timezone: $scope.timezone}`

Comment: @NMittal doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another directive (attribute type) with a high  priority (higher than ng-model /ng-model-option's) that watches the options object for changes and triggers a recompile. My apologies for lack of specifics, I'm on a phone :)

EDIT:
Looks like there's a directive called [kcd-recompile](http://kentcdodds.com/kcd-angular/#/kcd-recompile) that does exactly what I described. Here's a working [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/C9t1vn?p=preview), with some additional goodies for factoring in DST for american timezones.

HTML:

```
<div kcd-recompile="data.timezone">
  <div>
    <select ng-model="data.timezone" ng-options="x.offset as x.name for x in timezones">
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="date" ng-model="data.arrival" ng-model-options="{timezone: data.timezone}" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="time" ng-model="data.arrival" ng-model-options="{timezone: data.timezone}" />  
  </div>
</div>
```

And JS:

```
Date.prototype.stdTimezoneOffset = function() {
    var jan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    var jul = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 6, 1);
    return Math.max(jan.getTimezoneOffset(), jul.getTimezoneOffset());
}

Date.prototype.dst = function() {
    return this.getTimezoneOffset() < this.stdTimezoneOffset();
}

angular.module('DemoApp', ['kcd.directives']);
angular.module('DemoApp')
.controller('DemoCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var now = new Date(),
        isDst = now.dst();

    $scope.data ={
      arrival: now,
      timezone: null
    };
    $scope.timezones = [
      {
        name: 'PST', 
        offset: isDst ? '-0700' : '-0800'
      },
      {
        name: 'EST', 
        offset: isDst ? '-0400' : '-0500'
      }
    ];
  }]
);
```