# How do I make ng-model-options use dynamic variables?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I am having an issue where `ng-model-options` isn't reflecting the changes I need it to. 
For example, in the snippet below if you enter `4:00 pm` into both time inputs you'll see the UTC output is different - the first is `6` and the second is `8`. This is expected. However, the issue occurs when I select `+0800` using the dropdown. Since this updates the `timezone` variable, both `time` inputs should now display `8` when I enter `4:00 pm` since the first input should now use the `timezone` variable (as specified in its `ng-model-options`). However this isn't happening. Even after I clear the input and re-enter the time manually it still shows the incorrect time. How can I make the `timezone` option in `ng-model-options` use a dynamically changing variable such as `timezone`?

See issue below:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.timezones = ['+1000', '+0800'];
    $scope.timezone = $scope.timezones[0];

    $scope.time = '';
    $scope.eightTime = '';
  });

angular.element(document).ready(() => {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <select ng-model="timezone">
    <option ng-repeat="timezone in timezones" ng-value="timezone">{{timezone}}</option>
  </select>
  <p>Selected Timezone: {{timezone}}</p>

  <input type="time" ng-model="time" ng-model-options='{timezone: timezone}' />
  <p>Using dropdown T.Z of '{{timezone}}': {{time.getUTCHours()}}</p>

  <input type="time" ng-model="eightTime" ng-model-options="{timezone: '+0800'}">
  <p>Hardcoded '+0800': {{eightTime.getUTCHours()}}</p>
  <!-- ^^^ This should be the output when '+0800' is selected in the dropdown -->
</div>
```

Comment: have you looked into https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions#default-events-extra-triggers-and-catch-all-debounce-values ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions#programmatically-changing-options) -

> The ngModelOptions expression is only evaluated once when the
>   directive is linked; it is not watched for changes. However, it is
>   possible to override the options on a single `ngModel.NgModelController`
>   instance with `NgModelController#$overrideModelOptions()`

I have changed some of the lines to make it work for you :)

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.timezones = ['+1000', '+0800'];
    $scope.timezone = $scope.timezones[0];
    $scope.time = '';
    $scope.eightTime = '';
    
    $scope.$watch('timezone',function(v){
        $scope.time = '';
        $scope.myForm.time.$overrideModelOptions({'timezone': $scope.timezone}); 
        //this will update the options whenever the timezone will be changed.
    })
    
  });

angular.element(document).ready(() => {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <form name="myForm">
    <select ng-model="timezone" ng-options="timezone for timezone in timezones">
    </select> <!-- ng-options is the correct way to provide options to the select dropdown -->
    <p>Selected Timezone: {{timezone}}</p>

    <input type="time" name="time" ng-model="time" ng-model-options='{timezone: timezone}' />
    <p>Using dropdown T.Z of '{{timezone}}': {{time.getUTCHours()}}</p>
    <input type="time" ng-model="eightTime" ng-model-options="{timezone: '+0800'}">
    <p>Hardcoded '+0800': {{eightTime.getUTCHours()}}</p>
    <!-- ^^^ This should be the output when '+0800' is selected in the dropdown -->
  </form>
</div>
```

You will find more details about `$overrideModelOptions` here - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$overrideModelOptions

**Edited:**

You can achieve it by creating a separate directive.

**For versions >1.6.2 **

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['kcd.directives'])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.timezones = ['+1000', '+0800'];
    $scope.timezone = $scope.timezones[0];
    $scope.time = '';
    $scope.eightTime = '';
    
});
angular.module('kcd.directives', []).directive('kcdRecompile', ['$parse', function($parse) {
  'use strict';
  return {
    transclude: true,
    link: function link(scope, $el, attrs, ctrls, transclude) {
      var previousElements;

      compile();

      function compile() {
        transclude(scope, function(clone, clonedScope) {
          // transclude creates a clone containing all children elements;
          // as we assign the current scope as first parameter, the clonedScope is the same
          previousElements = clone;
          $el.append(clone);
        });
      }

      function recompile() {
        if (previousElements) {
          previousElements.remove();
          previousElements = null;
          $el.empty();
        }

        compile();
      }

      scope.$watch(attrs.kcdRecompile, function(_new, _old) {
        var useBoolean = attrs.hasOwnProperty('useBoolean');
        if ((useBoolean && (!_new || _new === 'false')) || (!useBoolean && (!_new || _new === _old))) {
          return;
        }
        // reset kcdRecompile to false if we're using a boolean
        if (useBoolean) {
          $parse(attrs.kcdRecompile).assign(scope, false);
        }
        recompile();
      }, typeof $parse(attrs.kcdRecompile)(scope) === 'object');
    }
  };
}]);

angular.element(document).ready(() => {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <div kcd-recompile="timezone">
    <select ng-model="timezone" ng-options="timezone for timezone in timezones">
    </select> <!-- ng-options is the correct way to provide options to the select dropdown -->
    <p>Selected Timezone: {{timezone}}</p>

    <input type="time" name="time" ng-model="time" ng-model-options="{timezone: timezone}"/>
    <p>Using dropdown T.Z of '{{timezone}}': {{time.getUTCHours()}}</p>
    <input type="time" ng-model="eightTime" ng-model-options="{timezone: '+0800'}">
    <p>Hardcoded '+0800': {{eightTime.getUTCHours()}}</p>
    <!-- ^^^ This should be the output when '+0800' is selected in the dropdown -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Reference Post - [Dynamically Setting ngModelOptions in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35806912/dynamically-setting-ngmodeloptions-in-angular)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I wasn't ware of `$overrideModelOptions`. However, unfortunately I cannot use it as I am using an angular version < 1.6.2 which doesn't have this method implemented. I cannot update my angular version as I am using a specific platform which enforces the version for me. Do you know of a way to achieve what `$overridemodelOptions` can in an earlier version of angular?

Comment: You can check the edited answer. That will fulfill your purpose. :)